# Pass known map to ROS navigation stack

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I've been using the [ros navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) with the turtlebot, but right now it's doing SLAM and constructing the map as it goes, is there a way to pass a known map to the map_server? Any tips or examples on how to do so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274742/pass-known-map-to-ros-navigation-stack./) by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 700 on 2017-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes.

See [wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials - Autonomous Navigation of a Known Map with TurtleBot](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/indigo/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map) fi.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-11-01**:
Thanks, I'll give it a look.